# Android room, map to existing model

Tags: android, android-room

I have a room database that stores a list of vacation resorts, which includes fields for State and Country, and am trying to get a distinct list of the State/Country combinations.

So far I have:

```
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT state,country from ResortdatabaseModel")
    List<StateModel> getAllStates();
```

However, StateModel is not an entity within the database, it's a model defined elsewhere in the project, and I'm getting an error "Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type "

How do I map the query results to the exiting model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `StateModel` needs to have the properties `state` and `country` with the same types as those two columns in `Resortdatabasemodel`, e.g.:

```
data class StateModel(
    val state: String,
    val country: String,
)
```

(`String` is just an example here, I don't know the actual types in your project)

Comment: Thank you, there were different names being used for state and country between the two, and changing the names to match in StateModel worked.